# Using modules in apk

Tags: ubuntu, kivy, apk, python-for-android

I have a kivyapp I want to launch it on my phone with buildozer, everything is working besides my modules that I use inside my .apk cant be found when my app is launched on the phone. I understand that these modules somehow needs to get imported to my apk, but how should this be done? I am doing this inside ubuntu.

Comment: If they are pip-installable, add them to the app requirements. If they are local code, copy them into your app dir so that they get installed along with everything else.

Comment: Kivymd is pip-installable but when I have it in my requirements, my logcat reader in my phone still shows “no module named kivymd” during the crash of my app launch.